# replace substring None with 'None'

Tags: python, replace

I want to change any `None` to `'None'` (note single quotes) in a JSON file that contains both already.

```
type: None or
type: 'None'
```

I tried `"s/[']?None[']?/'None'/g"` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are changing all `None` to `'None'`, wouldn't it be easier to just use `str.replace` with that json string? I'd run it in two procedures, first change `'None'` to `None`, then change all `None` to `'None'`.

Comment: thats what I am doing right now, but I am sure regex can do everything in one shot

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negative lookahead assertion `(?!...)`:

```
import re

test = "type: None or 'None'"

result = re.sub(r"None(?!')", r"'None'", test)
```

This will match `None` as long as it is not directly followed by a `'`.

[→ Regular Expression Syntax ←](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: You are also changing ``'None'`` to ``''None''``

Comment: Your second example replaces whatever is immediately before or after None with ' characters. Something like "(1,None,2)" would become "(1'None'2)". This may not be a problem in the original JSON file, as there may always be spaces around instances of None, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Gary Fixler Thanks. I agree it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/([^'])?(None)([^'])?/$1'$2'$3/g
```